# In iOS, what happens to objects attached to controllers when navigating?

Tags: ios, swift2

I am building an iOS app in Swift 2 and am typically creating a "Manager" class in each ViewController that holds a bit of data about that view in ViewDidLoad.  These are very lightweight objects so reloading them isn't a big deal.

But I am wondering about the typical lifecycle here: is "ViewDidLoad" called only when a UIViewController is first instantiated and the screen shown? Or is it called each time the user visits even if only via a "Back" from a subsequent screen? Is it called when an app is sent to background and re-opened?

Where would you place a data object that you'd like to refer to when displaying data? (Not in the persistent sense - I have that covered).

In a related vein, if I free up some memory in didReceiveMemoryWarning ("Dispose of any resources that can be recreated") then when would I recreate them? Is this only called when the view isn't loaded/shown so I could always do my check in viewDidLoad?

Any insight that you can give me into how object/in-memory persistence is managed in an iOS app is appreciated.

Comment: The lifecycle is covered in the "View Controller Programming Guide" in the iOS docs.

Comment: Thanks Maddy.  I am (obviously) new to Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you navigate away from a view controller either by pushing a new view controller or presenting a new view controller the original one is still in memory.

Any objects it has a strong reference to will be held in memory also.

If memory pressure gets too big then eventually your app will be killed by the OS. Before this happens your view controller will have the method `didReceiveMemoryWarning` triggered. (Even if not on screen). This is your opportunity to get rid of all that lightweight data that can easily be restored.

In terms of life cycle.

`init` is called once. (Obviously)

`viewDidLoad` is called once when the `view` property of the controller is first accessed.

`viewDidAppear`, `viewWillAppear`, etc... Are called multiple times. When the view is coming onto the screen or disappearing off the screen.

You can also use the properties `isBeingPresented` or `isMovingToParent` etc... To determine exactly why the view controller is appearing or disappearing. (There are a couple others that you can find in the docs).

In objective-c what I would do for this sort of data is create a lazy property that loads when it is first accessed. Then in the memory warning set that property to nil. Then when I need it again it will load again.

In swift I am sure there will be a similar way but I'm not 100% sure what it is.

Comment: Swift actually has lazy vars as well. Thanks for the answer!!